# fix html string from model to embed in view

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

here is the string in model returned. `"<table><tr><td></td><td>2003</td`>.." so its fine
but when it comes to view it becomes. "<table><tr><td></td&gt..."
when I encode and append it to element.

```
 var data = '@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.tablestr))';
    $("#divdt").empty();
    $("#divdt").append(data);
```

it display page the html string in text mode

```
table><tr><td></td><td>2003</td><td>2011</td><td>2012</td><td>2013</td><td>2014</td><td>TOPLAM</></tr><tr><td>ADANA</td><td><a href="Denetimler">0</a></td><td><a href="Denetimler">1</a></td><td><a href="Denetimler">1</a></td><td><a href="Denetimler">2</a></td><td><a href="Denetimler">0</a></td><td><a href="Denetimler">4</a><
```

How can I able to append this value as html element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `.Raw` and `.Encode` together doesn't seem to make much sense.  Try this instead:

```
 var data = '@Html.Raw(Model.tablestr)';
    $("#divdt").empty();
    $("#divdt").append(data);
```